# Where was Spock when the Enterprise B was launched?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock, star-trek-generations

As far as I remember, only Kirk, Scotty, and Chekov were the only ones from the original crew on the Enterprise B when it was commissioned in *Star Trek: Generations*.

Since Spock was higher up in the original ship's crew than Scotty / Chekov, why wasn't Spock there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [official novelization](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JgcBPdLLNzYC) of the film by J.M. Dillard explains several absences, not only Spock's but also those of McCoy, Uhura, and Sulu:

> He was not quite sure what prompted Kirk's sudden outburst of mulishness, except possibly the recent disappointing news that Spock and McCoy would not be joining them for the christening ceremony.  Nor would Uhura, who was vacationing in a far-off region of the galaxy before returning to teach at the Academy, or Sulu, who was off commanding the Excelsior...
>
> ...**Spock was involved with a diplomatic mission on behalf of Vulcan and could not free himself**...As for McCoy, he and his family were attending his granddaughter's graduation from the Vulcan Science Academy...

I interpreted the question as in-universe, but if you are also interested in out-of-universe reasons, here are some reasons why only Shatner, Doohan, and Koenig appear in the film:

- Leonard Nimoy was asked to appear (and even asked to direct), but he felt that the script had issues and that the lines given to Spock were quite bland and could have been given to any character.  He subsequently declined to be involved. Those lines were eventually given to Scotty, which Nimoy felt was proof that he was correct!
- DeForest Kelley's declining health meant he couldn't get on-set medical insurance; his McCoy lines were given to Chekov.
- George Takei was approached about reprising his role as Sulu for the Enterprise-B's helm officer, but he disliked the idea of Captain Sulu serving as a helm officer after having commanded the Excelsior. The character of his daughter, Demora Sulu, was created in response.

([Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/trivia))

Finally, a bit of **trivia**, in the spirit of your question: **this is the one and only time that Kirk has appeared in a Star Trek episode or film without Spock!**

Comment: Does McCoy have a green-blooded pointy-eared devil for a grand-daughter?!

Comment: The symmetry of a fully human McCoy descendant gaining admittance to The Vulcan Science Academy would be more pleasing. Given its prestige in Vulcan society, the good doctor might see his granddaughters accomplishment as sticking it to those green blooded, inhuman...

Comment: The absence of both Spock and McCoy has a continuity tie-in with a previous movie. Kirk has a line in Final Frontier explaining his confidence that despite the harrowing situations, he will not die because Spock and McCoy are present... he knows that when he dies, he will be alone. Generations fulfills Kirk's "prophecy" in two ways: not only is he alone in the section of the ship when it is struck by the Nexus, but Spock and McCoy aren't even aboard.